# check if sharepoint list exists

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm using Power Automate and I'm trying to check if a sharepoint list exists on my sharepoint online site. I managed to do this for Sharepoint groups using an HTTP request. so i did the same in this case but it doesn't seem to be working.

[image]

I create a variable that is an array, question the site, get the result and then depending on the fact that the array is empty or not, it goes in my condition.

the thing is if i set the variable as an array, it stops at my "Set Variable" and tells me the variable is an array and can't be initialized with a string.

if i set the variable as a string, it goes to the condition and  doesn't seem to figure out that the length of my variable is ... 0 ... so it goes on the NO side and crashes because the list doesn't exist.

would anyone be able to help me on this ?

thanks a lot and regards

Comment: After running the flow first time, check the output of "Send an HTTP request" action in run history. This will help you to understand what condition and what type of variable you should use.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. that's what i did... and that's why i can say why it's not working and what are the 2 errors.  but the HTTP request gives me the correct results, it shows me an array that is empty. so since my variable is an array...why is it saying that it needs a sttring.... when i did this in a workflow to check whether groups exists or not, it's working perfectly. but for the list it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to check the length of the results directly. Parse the results first and check the length. No need to set the variable. If the length is 0, then not exist.

[image]

Comment: Hello Jerry_MSFT, sorry for my late reply.  I just tried what you recommend and I still have an error  at the condition level (I test the length of the Title from the Parse action) "Unable to process template language expressions for action 'Condition' at line '1' and column '25518': 'The template language function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Null'. "  so parsing doesn't solve the issue. thanks anyway